# SharePoint 2010 Installation Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, administration, farm-admin

I am trying to install SharePoint 2010 in windows 7 ultimate ,And i face the bellow error.Can any one help me in knowing does it really required 20008 r2 to install **standalone**

[image]

Thanks & Regards,
Siddiq

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported to install the SharePoint 2010 on non server products that's why you are getting this error.

It is highly recommend configure the hyper v on the machine then spin a VM and install windows server to configure sharepoint.

But if you want this too be on Windows 7 then you can follow the below blog, you have to tweak some settings on the Windows and config file.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/spradip.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/installing-sharepoint-2010-in-windows-7-64-bit/amp/

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint can be installed on windows 7 also.

below is excerpt from MSDN. [Ref link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=24983)

SharePoint Foundation 2010 can also be installed for development purposes on Windows 7 and Windows Vista Service Pack 2. Installing on these operating systems is not supported for production deployments. For instructions on how to install on these operating systems, refer to Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008.

Now coming to your error. From this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx) it says that this error will come if step 3 is not done properly. putting steps here for quick reference. Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx) for details

3. Using a text editor such as Notepad, open the installation configuration file, config.xml, located in the following path: 
   c:\SharePointFiles\files\Setup\config.xml

Add this line inside the  tag:

```
<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>
```

4. Save the configuration file.
5. Review the complete configuration file. It now looks similar to the following for SharePoint Foundation 2010. The complete configuration file will be longer for SharePoint Server 2010 (and therefore the text below cannot replace the contents of that file), but should use the same setting for the AllowWindowsClientInstall attribute.

   ```
   < Configuration>
     <Package Id="sts">
       <Setting Id="SETUPTYPE" Value="CLEAN_INSTALL" />
     </Package>
     <DATADIR Value="%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
      Extensions\14\Data" />
     <Logging Type="verbose" Path="%temp%" Template="Microsoft Windows
      SharePoint Services 4.0 Setup *.log" />
     <PIDKEY Value="PIDKey Value" />
     <Setting Id="UsingUIInstallMode" Value="1" />
     <Setting Id="SETUP_REBOOT" Value="Never" />
     <Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>
   </Configuration>
   ```

All of the text in this configuration file is case-sensitive. If you do not edit the configuration file as described in the previous step or if you do not save the configuration file, when you try to run the installation you see the error message shown in Figure 1.
Figure 1. Setup is unable to proceed error message

[image: Setup is unable to proceed]

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint only support server based installation so it can not be installed in normal OS, for that you have to install server OS first and then you can install server in them

in that case you are installing SharePoint 2010 so minimum required server version is windows server 2008 R2